# Produce a nested object from array of objects with flat path

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to convert an array of objects, with each object in array having a path and id, into a tree that represents that path. for example the output is below for given input of  `[{path: 'foo/bar/baz', id: 1}]`

```json
[
    {
      "path": "foo",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "bar",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "baz",
              "children": [],
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

So far, i have the following code:

```js
const pathObjs = [
    { id: 1, path: 'foo/bar/baz' },
  ];

const result = [];
const level = { result };

for (p of pathObjs) {
  p.path.split('/').reduce((r, path) => {
    if (!r[path]) {
      r[path] = { result: [] };

      const p = { path, children: r[path].result };

      r.result.push(p);
    }

    return r[path];
  }, level);
}
```

I cannot figure out, how to assign the `id` of each path at the right level so that final result looks like:

```json
[
    {
      "path": "foo",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "bar",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "baz",
              "children": [],
              // how to add this guy here!
              "id": 1,
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

can someone nudge me toward the right direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making `const p` a local variable within the `reduce` callback, use a variable that is accessible after `reduce` has completed, so that you can access that last assigned object in order to add the additional property (or properties).

So change:

```
      const p = { path, children: r[path].result };
      r.result.push(p);
```

To:

```
      last = { path, children: r[path].result };
      r.result.push(last);
```

And define `last` as a local variable in the scope of the `for` block. After `reduce` has finished you can then use `Object.assign` to mutate that "leaf" object, adding the extra property/properties:

```
  Object.assign(last, rest); // rest is whatever needs to be added.
```

So your code could be modified as follows:

```
const result = [];
const level = { result };

for (p of pathObjs) {
  let last; // This will be the latest added object
  let { path, ...rest } = p; // Extract the path and the other properties
  path.split('/').reduce((r, path, i, {length}) => {
    if (!r[path]) {
      r[path] = { result: [] };

      last = { path, children: r[path].result };

      r.result.push(last);
    }

    return r[path];
  }, level);
  Object.assign(last, rest); // Extend with the extra properties.
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias 

Answer (score 0):

This solution restructures your original code. The primary difference is that the path list is reversed, so we start at the leaf node instead of the root.

There is an explicit check to see if we're at the first index (which we can assume it's the leaf). Alternatively, you could instead check if `result` is defined or not and rely on that instead of the index if you prefer.

```js
const pathObjects = [{ id: 1, path: "foo/bar/baz" }];

const result = [];

for (let { id, path } of pathObjects) {
  const obj = path
    .split("/")
    .reverse()
    .reduce((result, path, index) => {
      const node = {
        path,
        children: result ? [result] : []
      };

      if (index === 0) {
        node.id = id;
      }

      return node;
    }, null);

  result.push(obj);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: hmm i see. though the output of above code has duplicate parent nodes. for example for input of `[{ id: 1, path: "foo/bar/baz" }, { id: 2, path: "foo/bar/bax" }]` instead of `foo.bar` having have two children `[baz, baz]`, there's two separate foo.bar with two different children?